# Android SQLite sólo me deja guardar un campo pero no varios

Tags: android, sqlite

Estoy haciendo un diccionario de idiomas donde el usuario puede añadir palabras pero sólo me deja añadir un campo, si pongo varios ya no.

Así sí me deja guardar:

```
  public void palabranueva(View v) {
    int _id;
    String p_esp;

    p_esp = espanol.getText().toString();
    sql mi_sql = new sql(insert.this, "diccionario", null, 1);
    if (mi_sql != null) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = mi_sql.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues idioma = new ContentValues();
        idioma.put("espanol", p_esp);

        long insertado = db.insert("diccionario", null, idioma);
        if (insertado > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(insert.this, "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(insert.this, "No se ha guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            espanol.setText("");
         }
       }
   }
}
```

Pero si pongo más campos siempre me sale el toast de que no se ha guardado. Esto ya me lo rechazara:

```
 public void palabranueva(View v) {
    int _id;
    String p_esp, p_fr, p_eng;

    p_esp = espanol.getText().toString();
    p_fr = francais.getText().toString();
    p_eng = english.getText().toString();

    sql mi_sql = new sql(insert.this, "diccionario", null, 1);
    if (mi_sql != null) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = mi_sql.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues idioma = new ContentValues();
       idioma.put("espanol", p_esp);
       idioma.put("francais", p_fr);
       idioma.put("english", p_eng);

       long insertado = db.insert("diccionario", null, idioma);
       if (insertado > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(insert.this, "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(insert.this, "No se ha guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            espanol.setText("");
            francais.setText("");
            english.setText("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

La base de datos es

```
"CREATE TABLE diccionario (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, espanol TEXT, francais TEXT, english TEXT)";
```

Comment: cual es el logcat del error?

Comment: No sale ningún error, carga perfectamente en el teléfono pero al darle a guardar no guarda cuando hay más de un campo

Comment: Buenas compañero @KaixoGuit, verificaste antes de añadir a los parámetros de tu ContentValues que tus variables no estén nulas ? `p_esp` `p_fr` `p_eng`

Comment: Compañero @Nicethunder Lo acabo de hacer pero nada...

Comment: ya veo solo por si acaso, si le pones un break a esta linea `long insertado = db.insert("diccionario", null, idioma);` como se muestra la variable `idioma`?

Comment: Tampoco... bueno da igual, lo borré todo y volví a empezar cambiando el if-else por un try-catch y ahora sí me funciona. O ha sido eso o tenía un fallo en algún detalle pequeño. Gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Realizaste una prueba en una tabla conteniendo aolo un campo y posteriormente dcambiaste el query pero solo insertaba un campo. Revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso seguramente creaste una base de datos conteniendo la tabla con un campo, es muy común que no se realicé cambio de estructura en la tabla ya que el método `onCreate()` o el método `onUpgrade()`, no se vuelve a ejecutar nuevamente.

Lo recomendable es borrar los datos de la aplicación para que se vuelva a llamar el método que crea la estructura correcta de tabla o simplememte elimina y vuelve a instalar la aplicación.

Comment: ¿Hay que borrar los datos de la App para que vuelva a crearla? Ok, no lo sabía y segurísimo que era eso. Gracias Jorgesys!!